# Raspberry Pi 2 - apt-get install not working after failed Mongodb compile

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi

I've had a look through the answers on stack already and none of them seem to work, I tried installing MongoDB on my pi and unfortunately experienced a power cut whilst it was running, whenever I try and UPDATE or install via apt-get I encounter...

```
pi@raspberrypi /var/lib/apt/lists $ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Hit http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy Release
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi armhf Packages
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3                                                                                                             .0/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages' in                                                                                                              Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used                                                                                                              instead.
```

I can't find where the entry for that mondo repo is, i've grep'd for it with no success, any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: `grep -Hnr 'repo\.mongodb\.org' /etc` should point you towards that file.

Comment: Aha yeah gotcha thanks for that, wanna put an answer up, I just deleted the Mongo source from that directory and all good again now